# Using Least Squares Method to find the Tangent Planes to a Sphere at any point on the sphere?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my linear algebra class, we are currently solving problems like,

1. You have three points on a plane, let's call them (O,U,V). We will assume O is the origin.
2. You 'drop' a perpendicular from a fourth point (let's call it W) that is not on the plane
3. Use the least-squares method to find where this foot of the perpendicular will be on the plane

And using the three points on the plane we construct two vectors, v and u, that connect to the respective points U and V and intersect at the middle point O. We create a third vector w that goes from that middle point O to point W.

We use this equation Ax=b, but in the form [u v]x=[w] this works since O is the origin. This is unsolveable so then we use the least squares method, x=(AtA)^-1 (Atb) to solve for x. The "foot of the perpendicular" is Ax. The distance from the foot of the perpendicular on the plane and the point W is ε, which is what you need to add back in to Ax = b on the left to actually equal b and not just approximate it like we did.

So, now I have a different kind of question. I have the equation of a sphere, (x-2)^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4 and need to find tangent planes to it that pass through the points (0,1,0) and (0,0,2). There are other ways to solve it but I want to figure out how to solve it like above.

1. Consider the foot of the perpendicular dropped from the center of the sphere to this plane to be point p = (x1,y1,z1). We will construct two vectors v and u using the points (0,1,0) and (0,0,2) that intersect at this point p.
2. The distance between point p and the center of the sphere is 2.
3. Ax=b or [u v] x = [w] will be more complex as each vector is written in terms of the distance of the point U, V, or W from point p which is unknown or = (x1,y1,z1).

How do I solve this question? I tried to first solve for x using the least-squares method and then computing Ax which would give me the foot of the solution, but I have too many variables. Can anybody solve this for me using this method?

Comment: I was hoping someone could show me how I can solve the above question from my assignment using this method, which is to find the foot of the perpendicular(s) between all the tangent planes of a sphere and its center knowing only the equation of the sphere and two points on the plane. Then using the coordinates of the perpendicular to find the equation(s) of the tangent plane(s). It is mainly how can I fit this problem into this "method". I've solved the problem using other ways but I want to be able to find the foot of the perpendicular and then the plane using that foot and two given points.

Comment: Are you connected with the person that has asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4279993) ?

Comment: No, I don't know who that is but they are probably in my class. My question pertains to how to get the solution using the above method as I have already solved the question.